# C# Interface reference to inherited type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface

How can I define the type of child interfece in interface, please see sample code

```
public interface IParent<T>: IList<T>
{
    <child_interface> Children { get; }
}

public interface IChildA: IParent<SomeType>{}
```

I want to have in `<child_interface>` the type of the inherited Interface (IChildA, IChildB...etc)

Is it even possible ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use generic constraints

Comment: Do you mean `public interface IChildA: IParent<IChildA>{}`

Answer (score 0):

Add a second generic type parameter to the parent interface. You can also include a type constraint too:

```
public interface IParent<T, TChild> : IList<T>
    where TChild : IParent<T, TChild>
{
    TChild Children { get; }
}
```

Now use it like this:

```
public interface IChildA : IParent<SomeType, IChildA> 
{
}
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the aswer, I've tried that but i want if there is a way that the parent interfece could guess its child, somthing like CallerMemberName attribut

Comment: No, you need to be explicit

Comment: For example in your code, when defining IChildA, there is no way to reference itself in secound part right ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

What @DavidG said, but another way is to not use generics:

```
public interface IParent
{
    List<IChild> Children { get; }
}
```